# TYPO3: femanager add field to registration

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

Because of the new European law I have to add a "Privacy policy" checkbox to the registration form.
We use "femanager" for the registration.
I did add a attribute "privacy" in the user entity and added a checkbox to the form:

```
<f:form.checkbox id="privacy" property="privacy" value="0" />
```

I also set the validator in the typoscript settings under: plugin.tx_femanager.settings.new.validation

```
privacy {
                required = 1
            }
```

unfortunately the validation doesn't seem to work.

Comment: IIRC there is a tutorial in the extension documentation and even an example inside the extension itself (can't remember the folder), am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a wrong path in your TypoScript-Settings.

```
plugin.tx_femanager.settings.new.validation {
    privacy {
        required = 1
    }
}
```

Try this. :)

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in the original post. I actually use your path which is correct